# Why after deploy my working spider to cloud platform it now only get 400 response?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I have use scrapyd to deploy my spider to cloud platform. The spider works fine on local computer. But now it only get http 400 response. Is it banned ? or the hardware can’t handle the frequent request ? I am using the lowest spec.

Normally in my local computer the response are in http 200 status.

Here is the debug log:

2020-05-04 04:04:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) https://website I scrape.com> (referer: https://website I scrape.com&_ac=1)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the website is blocking traffic coming from ip-addresses of cloud providers. You can still get around this, but you'll have to use proxies.

Comment: but when I use wget to go to the website. It is not banned